# Can I use another support library apart from AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I tried using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1 but still I get the followwing errors.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Preview timed out while rendering the layout.
This typically happens when there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views.
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.getZipFile(JarLoader.java:173)
at com.intellij.util.lang.JarLoader.getResource(JarLoader.java:130)
at com.intellij.util.lang.ClassPath.getResource(ClassPath.java:120)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._getResource(UrlClassLoader.java:279)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(UrlClassLoader.java:287)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:77)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:164)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:91)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:164)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:91)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:164)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:91)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:164)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:91)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:164)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:91)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.defineClassAndPackage(RenderClassLoader.java:164)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFromJar(RenderClassLoader.java:91)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:90)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:193)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.<clinit>(ViewCompat.java:1821)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:84)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:59)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:238)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:150)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$53(RenderTask.java:659)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$$Lambda$214/686478171.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: `there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views`... What did you do??

Comment: Off the cuff, it would appear that you are running into an Android Studio bug, preventing it from rendering a preview of your UI. If you are not on Android Studio 2.2.2, you might wish to move to that version. If you are on Android Studio 2.2.2, and you can create a project that reproduces this problem, you could [file an issue](http://b.android.com), so that perhaps this bug can get fixed.

Comment: ya I just installed the latest version i.e. Android Studio 2.2.2 and still it's the same , i will file an issue now. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi cricket_007 I just upgraded Android studios that's all I did and since then the app I'm developing doesn't work.